# NTP Server Precedence using systemd-timesyncd

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, ntp

I'm looking for documentation which specifies the precedence / priority of NTP servers (ubuntu 20.04).

I am using timesyncd which has the ntp.ubuntu server
But when connecting to the network via DHCP I want to use the NTP sever which my DHCP server is using - thus i have option 42 set for my systemd-networkd settings.  In the case in which the DHCP server does not offer NTP server information, does the system fall back to the timesyncd server?

Can anyone point me towards and documentation which might lead me in the right direction?  thank you